# Ensuring you're reading a character through scanf

Tags: c, string, do-while

Is there a simple way to make sure you're reading a character through scanf. If it were an integer I'd use a do while loop

```
      do{
        printf("enter a number");
        fehler = scanf(" %d", &x);
        getchar();
        } while(fehler!=1);
```

But I'm not fully sure what to do if the input is meant to be a string. I know the alphabets are stored as ASCII values but the if constraints in the while statement don't seem to be working(unless I'm doing it wrong)

```
      char * temp2;
      temp2 = malloc(sizeof(string));

      do{
       printf("PLease enter a string: ");
       scanf(" %s", temp2);
       getchar();
      } while(temp2 <= 'A' && temp2 <= 'z')
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  You just have to check the value returned by `scanf`.  It will tell you how many conversion specifiers were matched.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That won't tell if the input contains only alphabetic characters.

Comment: It may be easier if you used [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `scanf`. For example, `scanf(" %s", temp2);` will only read one word, not the entire line. You may want to read this: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: @Barmar It will if you use the correct conversion specifier.  eg `"%1[a-zA-Z]"`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Checking scanf's return value would work with digits but I am not sure about the string

Comment: But `scanf` is absolutely the wrong tool for this.

Comment: @WilliamPursell But if you do that, you won't  easily be able to get past the bad input, you'll be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: `scanf` is designed for formatted input.  If the input does not match the expectation, the correct response is to abort with an error message, not to loop and try again.  If the input is coming from a human being, the program should probably not be written in C.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Why shoudn't the programming language C be able to handle actual user input? I agree that `scanf` should not be used in this case, but what is wrong with `fgets`?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel "what is wrong with fgets" --> `fgets()` weaknesses include: 1) lack of clear excessive long input detection/handling 2) lack of knowing input length in the presence of reading a null character.  3) `n` parameter is inconsistently `int` and not `size_t` 4) by some: retaining the `'\n'` 5) input not certainly null character terminated on end-of-file or input error.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare a string to a single character. You have to loop through the entire string, checking every character.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int is_alphabetic(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (!isalpha(str[i])) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

...
do{
    printf("Please enter an alphabetic string: ");
    scanf(" %s", temp2);
    getchar();
} while(!is_alphabetic(temp2));
```

Comment: The code above will accept the input "alphabetic 772", because `scanf(" %s", temp2);` only consumes "alphabetic" and not the " 772". I think `fgets` would be a better choice.

Comment: Thank You, this seems to be working fine. But I'll look into fgets as well!

Answer (score 0):

You see printf and scanf work independently. Whatever you store be it a character or number is stored in form of a number. Now it depends on the printf function what it demands.
Eg.: If you store 'a' at a location, the number 97 is stored. Now if you print a number it prints 97 and if you demand a character it gives a.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i = 97;
printf("%d \n", i);
printf("%c", i);
return 0;
}
```

See the results. Further char, int , long int are just data types which specify the number of bits that would be resrved for the inputs for the variable.

Execute this program and you'll understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i;
for (i=97; i <=200 ; i++)
{
    printf("%d  %c,\t",i,i);
};
return 0;}
```

This will show you a nmber when printed as a number and then the SAME number read as character.
Note there are no markers in memory to store which type of data it is. It is straightforward stored as number.

Answer (score -1):

`scanf` is absolutely the wrong tool for this.  But if you want to read only alphabetic characters, you can do it easily enough with something like:

```
char s[32];
if( 1 == scanf(" %31[a-zA-Z]", s) ){ ... }
```

The `%31[a-zA-Z]` conversion specifier will match only the literal characters `a` thru `z` and `A` thru `Z`, and will only consume up to 31 characters of input.  You must always use a field width modifier with `%s` or `%[]` conversion specifiers to avoid an overflow.